# Codeigniter how to map a class sent to a model

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, frameworks, model

I have a SectorModel with this function:

```
public function update(Sector $sector) {
        $this->db->where('sector_id', $sector->getScetor_id());
        return $this->db->update(_SECTOR_, $sector);
}
```

There are times that I’ll change only the name of the Sector object:

```
$Sector = new Sector();
$Sector->setSector_name = 'test';

$this->SectorModel->update($Sector);
```

The generated select looks like:

```
UPDATE realestate_sector SET sector_name = 'teste', sector_description = NULL
```

It will update but will set all other properties to NULL because it was not set on my object.
Right now, I have to fill the whole object before sending it.

Is there a way to map the Sector class and update only what was sent on the object?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Sorry for any typos, my English is not good =)

Comment: you could unset NULL properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through all your object's properites and then if any is `NULL` just drop it with **[unset](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)**.

Here is your model's method edited to achieve that:

```
public function update(Sector $sector)
{
   foreach($sector as $k=>$v)
   {
      if($v === NULL)
         unset($sector->$k)
   }

   $this->db->where('sector_id', $sector->getScetor_id());
   return $this->db->update(_SECTOR_, $sector);
}
```

**[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)** you can find some info about iterating objects in PHP

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to do this would be to rather use a array - docs here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#update - you just create a array of all the columns with their values that you want to update and perform a `$this->db->update('mytable', array('name' => 'test'), array('id' => $id));` call. This will only update the columns you specified in the First array. With the second array acting as your WHERE expression.

The only reason I can think of as to why your other values are being set to NULL is because in your example you create a new instance of the class and the other values must either have been set to nothing or are set to NULL. It would (If this is the case) be better to get a record from the table and then change and values on the populated record and pass that to the function to update.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Johann, I'm getting the record and populating the object but that is a lot of work and for every update I have to make a Select and that's not good. About the array, I have a lot of column on the database so it will be very laborious to do that with all updates and inserts.....